# angular material md-dynamic-height="" or md-dynamic-height

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I see that in all angular material code pens you get this: md-dynamic-height="" however other places it is used so md-dynamic-height without ="".

Can you tell me which one is correct and why?

for instance:

```
<div ng-cloak="" class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight" >
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>Tab 1</p> .....
```

In this code pen: http://codepen.io/1kohei1/pen/MaOMQa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are the same. because once md-dynamic-height appears, the default value is true. What will make things different is md-dynamic-height="false".

see source code https://github.com/angular/material/blob/0b89a877ad31d0f7d425272f29d8c02600a12a88/src/components/tabs/js/tabsController.js